# Why do the code shows tons of error whenever i type in alphabet input

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I have an upcoming assignment that creates a menu that creates a function whenever the users enter the input. Here is the problem, whenever I enter a number the code shows a normal invalid option. For alphabetic input, however, it started to appear tons of errors. Does anyone know how to solve this issue

```
   import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
poly = turtle.Turtle()
wn.setup(1000, 600)
poly.pensize(2)
poly.fillcolor('lightblue')
poly.penup()
poly.goto(-400, 15)
poly.pendown()


def menu():
    print(' *********************************')
    print('1. Draw polygons')
    print('2. Draw a flower')
    print('3. Exit')
    task = int(input('Enter an option (1/2/3): '))
    return task


def draw_shape(t, sides):
    for i in range(0, sides):
        t.forward(50)
        t.stamp()
        t.left(360 / sides)
        t.forward(50)


def draw_flower(t, sides):
    for i in range(0, sides):
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(100)
        t.left(137.5)
        t.forward(60)
        t.left(80)
        t.forward(70)


das = menu()
if das == 1:
    for angle in [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]:
        poly.penup()
        poly.forward(100)
        poly.pendown()
        poly.begin_fill()
        draw_shape(poly, angle)
        poly.end_fill()


elif das == 2:
    poly.pencolor('cyan')
    wn.bgcolor('light yellow')
    poly.speed(4)
    poly.penup()
    poly.goto(0, 0)
    poly.pendown()
    draw_flower(poly, 52)
    poly.forward(-100)

elif das == 3:
    print('Program exists. Have a nice day')
    exit()

else:
    print('Invalid option')

. Draw polygons
2. Draw a flower
3. Exit
Enter an option (1/2/3): sa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jonny/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Polygon and flowers.py", line 40, in <module>
    das = menu()
  File "C:/Users/jonny/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Polygon and flowers.py", line 18, in menu
    task = int(input('Enter an option (1/2/3): '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sa'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python interpreter is basically telling you that it cannot parse `'sa'` into an int, which is to be expected right?

When prompted to enter an option, if you enter `sa`, `input(...)` returns exactly that: `sa`, as a string.
At that point in your script, `task = int(input(...))` essentially becomes `task = int('sa')`.

#### Exceptions

Now put yourself in the shoes of function `int()`: you receive a string, and you must return an integer.
What do you do when the input string, `'sa'` for that matter, does **not** correctly represent an integer?

- You cannot return an integer, because that would imply that you parsed the string successfully.
- Returning something else than an integer would make no sense (and would be a pain to work with).

So you **throw an exception**: the execution flow is interrupted, and a specific kind of object, an *exception*, is *thrown*.

#### Exception handling

When a function throws an exception, it is interrupted: it does not finish running, it does not return anything, and the thrown exception is forwarded to the calling function. If that function decides to *catch* that exception (i.e. to handle it), then good, the normal execution flow can resume at that point.
If it decides **not** to handle the exception, then that function is interrupted too and the exception is forwarded yet again to the calling function. It continues in a similar fashion until the exception is caught, or until "no calling function is left", at which point the Python interpreter takes over, halts the execution of your script, and displays info about that exception (which is what happened in your case).

#### A first solution

If you're new to Python, maybe you shouldn't worry too much about handling exceptions right now. More generally, if you try to handle every possible case when it comes to user input, you're in for a wild ride.

**For the sake of completeness though:**
In order for your code to do what you expect, replace the `das = menu()` line with this:

```py
try:             # Enter a section of code where exceptions may be thrown
    das = menu() # menu() may throw an exception because of the int(...) inside

except:          # 'Catch' any exception that was thrown using an `except` block
    das = -1     # Set a dummy, invalid value
```

With this code, if `menu()` throws an exception (when you enter `sa` for example), it will be caught: the `try` block will be interrupted, and the `except` block will be executed. `das` will receive value `-1`, which by the rest of your code is invalid, and thus `Invalid option` will be displayed. This is much better than having your whole script halted!
On the other hand, if no exception is thrown by `menu()`, the `try` block will reach its end normally, and the `except` block will **not** be executed.

#### A better solution

However, this is not ideal. The exception should not be handled around `menu()`, it should be handled around `int(...)` *inside* your `menu` function.
You could do this as an exercise: first handle the exception inside `menu`, and then try to loop over the `int(input(...))` statement until a valid value is entered by the user.

There again, exception handling is not necessarily trivial and can be hard to get right, especially for beginners. So don't get frustrated if it seems like a not-so-useful overcomplication to you, there will come a point where you realize you can't go without them.

You can read more about exceptions here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp or here if you want a more comprehensive tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much . And also                                                                                                   Ore wa ochinchin ga daisuki nandayo